# Duda con estructuración de proyecto MEAN concreto

Tags: nodejs, angular, mongodb

Normalmente partimos de la base de que un usuario puede o no acceder a ciertas tablas en función de su rol.

Pero, ¿Cómo se gestionaría que un usuario pueda acceder a una tabla u otra en función de su rol pero, además, en función de si tiene permiso para hacer operaciones CRUD en función de su autoría sobre la tabla?

Imaginemos, por poner un ejemplo, que tenemos usuarios (con su usuario, contraseña y si están activos) y que estos usuarios pueden ser de diferentes tipos (Estudiante, Profesor, Administrador) y en función del tipo que sean van a tener una serie de relaciones asociadas.

Tendríamos una tabla Usuario con los datos generales y otras tablas de subtipo con los datos del subtipo en concreto y las relaciones que tienen asociadas.

¿Deberíamos dar de alta en Usuario y subtipo (por ejemplo Estudiante) al realizar el registro en la aplicación o hacerlo de otra forma? ¿Debemos indicar en Usuario y subtipo el mismo valor para la clave?
¿Cómo se gestionaría la comprobación de si un usuario es o no el dueño del registro?

He estado intentando investigar este tipo de cuestiones en diferentes lugares y foros pero no encuentro solución al problema en ningún sitio.

¿Podrían ayudarme con esto?

Muchas gracias,

EDITO: Añado conceptualmente la solución actual, ya que es un problema a nivel de diseño y de concepto, no de implementación. En la actualidad cuando doy de alta un Usuario, doy de alta también mediante una transacción su subtipo (Estudiante, Profesor o Admin) pero no me convence esto.

```
Usuario:
   Id (el asignado por Mongo)
   correo (único)
   contraseña
   activo
   rol (Estudiante, Profesor o Admin)
   
Estudiante:
  Id (el mismo asignado en Usuario)
  pruebas (array de Prueba, otra colección)
  profesor (referencia a la colección Profesor)
  ...
  
Profesor:
  id (el mismo asignado en Usuario)
  alumnos_asignados
  pruebas_asignadas
  pruebas_resueltas
  ...
  
Admin:
  id (el mismo asignado en Usuario)
  incidencias_pend
  ...
```

Comment: En mi opinión, es bastante difícil entender un problema si no tienes un extracto de la información que se quiere ordenar. Puedes poner algo? No importa que sean datos teóricos, o que estén expresados en otra tecnología. De otra manera, la pregunta es bastante dificil de contestar.

Comment: Hola Legna, he editado el Post para añadir con pseudocódigo el diseño actual. No quise meter código a posta porque es un problema más a nivel conceptual, no de cómo implementarlo, pero tienes razón en que es mejor para que se entienda mejor el problema. Gracias por contestar.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente solo existe el usuario. Dentro del usuario tienes las propiedades embedidas:

> ## USUARIO
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Id (el asignado por Mongo)
> correo (único)
> contraseña
> activo
> rol (Estudiante, Profesor o Admin) ==> Debe ser un string
> // Lo expresas como un objeto dentro de usuario para mantener separadas sus 
>  //propiedades
> estudiante:{ }
> profesor:{ }
> permissions:["admin"] //Puede ser tambien 'profesor', 'alumno', etc.
> ```

Esta parte solo es para organizar. Por facilidad y versatilidad, en express, puedes autenticarte con jwt (json web token) . En el token, agregas los permisos para cada grupo de rutas.

## Generar un token

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es que cuando tu usuario se haga login, se genere un token. Para esto puedes usar [jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

```javascript
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'shhhhh');
```

## Decodificar el token

En esta sección del código puedes utilizar alguna librería como [express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) para decodificar el token:

```javascript
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
 
app.get('/protected',
  //Este es el middleware que se decodifica
  jwt({ secret: 'shhhhhhared-secret' }),
  //Este segundo middleware obtiene en req.user el usuario
  //decodificado desde el token. 
  function(req, res) {
    //Esto es como un hola mundo, pero de permisos. 
    if (!req.user.admin) return res.sendStatus(401);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
```

## Comprobar permisos

Con el usuario correctamente decoficado, ahora si podemos entrar en la gestión de permisos. La idea es que un archivo de rutas, con sus respectivos sub-archivos de ser necesario, controle una tabla o, como prefiero yo, un grupo de acciones relacionadas para asignar permisos a esas rutas.

Puedes hacerlo manualmente agregando un middleware como este:

```javascript
app.use("/cosasDeProfesor", 
(req, res, next)=>{//Lógica para comprobar el permiso}, 
cosasDeProfesorRoutes )
```

O tambien ya hay librerías que nos facilitan la vida como [express-jwt-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt-permissions).

```javascript
var guard = require('express-jwt-permissions')()
 
app.get("/cosasDeProfesor", guard.check('profesor'), cosasDeProfesoresRoutes)
app.get('/cosasDeAlumnos', guard.check(['alumos:leer']), cosasDeAlumnosRoutes)
```

## Registro de permisos.

Generalmente me gusta trabajar con un permiso por operación. Asi que genero una cantidad exorbitante de permisos en mis aplicaciones. Para mitigar la fátiga de administrar y registrar nuevos permisos cree una libreria que incluye `express-jwt-permissions` y que también crea un fichero donde los va a registrando. Si te interesa [es esta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@codice-progressio/easy-permissions)

Comment: Hola Legna. Pero conceptualmente, la solución que propones tiene los inconvenientes de que realmente quien tiene la relación no es el usuario, sino el tipo concreto de usuario (lo que trae como consecuencia que tendríamos que generar índices parciales y en Angular que al acceder a cualquiera de los subdocumentos nos metamos en la lógica del Guard)

Comment: No habría otra forma de hacerlo? Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: En realidad te manejas por permisos, cualquier usuario podría realizar cualquier operación con los permisos adecuados. En MongoDB no suelen usarse las relaciones, un mismo documento de usuario contiene todas las propiedades de cada tipo de usuario que describes. Así mitigas las relaciones entre tablas como se manejan en SQL. Dependiendo de la implementación que quieras hacer esto se puede hacer sin librerias, solo revisando el rol del usuario logueado, pero sin token esto requiere una lectura a la BD cada vez que hagas una petición.

Comment: No es eso lo que busco. Los campos estan referenciados en lugar de enlazados, siguiendo las recomendaciones de mongo, porque preveo que sean muchos y ademas hagan el documento muy pesado.

Comment: La recomendación de mongo es la de crear la menor cantidad de colleciones siempre que se pueda. A diferencia de SQL, la normalización de las BD de datos se da menos y se prefiere duplicar datos,  en ocasiones, para mejorar la lectura de los mismos. Además, por diseño, puedes seleccionar por defecto los campos que se van a traer dependiendo de la operación que tengas que realizar. Esto en su mayoría se resuelve en la api con las diferentes operaciones.

Comment: Sí, por eso he duplicado algunos datos (por ejemplo contadores) y he referenciado otros que por volumen estimado de filas tengo que tener separados en colecciones separadas. El problema está como manejar esta estructura (o con pequeñas variaciones de la misma que no incluyan meterlas en subdocumentos).

Comment: La recomendación de Mongo es que, en casos que esperemos que tengamos muchos documentos enlazados (lo que ellos llaman relaciones uno a zillions) o hagan que el peso del documento exceda de 16Mb en lugar de utilizar subdocumentos, referenciemos.